# passing variables of php in script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);
$row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
$row4 = mysql_fetch_array($result4);
echo $row4;
$row5=10;


?>
<script>

var t = new PieChart({
    container: document.getElementById("demo"),
    area: { height: 350 },
    data: {
        preloaded: {
            subvalues: [
                { id: "pun", value:x, style: { expandable: false } },
                { id: "tec", value: 20, style: { expandable: false } },
                { id: "hel",value:50,style:{expandable:false}},
                { id: "int",value:10,style:{expandable:false}},
                { id: "stu",value:10,style:{expandable:false}}
            ]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

how to pass value of "x" in for php.if using; it is not showing pie chart.using json encode is also not working

Comment: ...value:<?php echo $x  ?>, style:....

Comment: Can you reformulate the question? It's hard to see whats your problem. What you want to say with `how to pass value of "x" in for php.if using; it is not showing pie chart.`

Comment: how can i pass value of x from php

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a PHP code inside.

```
<script>
var t = new PieChart({
    container: document.getElementById("demo"),
    area: { height: 350 },
    data: {
        preloaded: {
            subvalues: [
                { id: "pun", value: <?php echo (int)$x; ?>, style: { expandable: false } },
                { id: "tec", value: 20, style: { expandable: false } },
                { id: "hel",value:50,style:{expandable:false}},
                { id: "int",value:10,style:{expandable:false}},
                { id: "stu",value:10,style:{expandable:false}}
            ]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```